# Error message :File extension changes to .aspx on opening any excel or word file in a sharepoint document library

Tags: 2007, document-library, error, excel

I have a document library in Sharepoint 2007 which consists of few word and excel files.
Whenever i try to open a file, it shows the message " the file [filename.aspx] you are trying to open is in a different format, Do you want to open it".

Now when i click on YES, it opens in excel but nothing is displayed.
**The issue is that the extension changes to ".aspx" automatically for both excel and word file when i try to open.**

Comment: Are the Word and Excel files OK? I mean, how have they been uploaded, and is the file extension correct (.docx, .xlsx)? Have they been created normally with Word/Excel?

Comment: @JussiPalo:Thanks for the reply.
Yes, the files are ok and were created by Word/Excel. Other users are able to access it properly.

Comment: So this only occurs in your browser? Have you tried another browser? What is different between you and the other users who don't see this behavior? Permissions? Browser? Office client version?